# Is it possible to run multiple classes using Ant after compilation?

Tags: java, ant

I'm totally new to StackOverflow so please try to  tolerate me.Thank you.I'm new to ANT with a beginners knowledge in java. So I wanted to know if it is possible to run multiple classes of java source files in an xml file using Ant.

Instead of specifying multiple java classnames within the targets, can I run the run classes in a single go?

[image: codes]

Comment: Okay, I'm getting an error as invalid or corrupt java file. How am I supposed to enter the code if class files are in a directory named dest which is under Ant directory? What I've done is :  <classpath>
        <pathelement location="/Ant/dest">
      </classpath>                                                                                         I couldn't understand exactly of what we need to specify, can you help?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots when posting actual code will do. Post your code as text.

Comment: This _might be_ a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297354/how-to-modify-build-xml-to-run-multiple-files-in-that-order - a question about running independent processes simultaneously.  On face value though, it looks like OP is asking whether a `java` task can be configured to run more than one class.

Comment: @Aravind - please can you replace the screenshot with the actual code and clarify the question?

Comment: Ya, I tried but I don't know actually on how to indent the code here since I'm new to StackOverflow and I was in a hurry, thank you for your feedback and I do consider your opinions.

Comment: Click on "edit" at the bottom left of the question above.  The editor will appear.  There is a toolbar with a question mark "?" at the right you can use to access helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed asking whether a java task can be configured to run more than one class I believe the answer is no. According to the [documentation for the java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) the `classname` attribute specifies

> the Java class to execute.

If you need to run multiple classes using a single java task you could create a controller class to run these classes then simply invoke that single controller.